# Delete column in Excel if certain row is blank

Tags: vb.net, excel

This has baffled me because any time I run a for each loop, and have it delete the column as a result, it throws off the loop end ultimately ends up missing columns.

I.e. if column 1 and 2 are ok, but 3 is not, it deletes 3, which causes 4 to be skipped because 4 becomes the new 3. Thus the script goes straight to  5.

I tried doing one for each and saving each column that needed to be deleted to a list, and then another for each that loops through the columns and deletes, but I have the same issue. Once a column gets deleted, all column numbers change.

Any ideas?

```
            For Each del In delRng.Cells

            currentcol = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(del.Column)

            If finalsheet.Range(currentcol & "3").Value = Nothing Then


                delCols.Add(del.Column)

else

                trimmer = finalsheet.Range(currentcol & "1").Value
                trimmer = trimmer.Substring(0, trimmer.IndexOf(" -"))
                finalsheet.Range(currentcol & "1").Value = trimmer

            End If
        Next



        For Each delMe As Long In delCols

            With finalsheet
                .Columns(delMe).delete()
            End With

        Next
```

Comment: The loop where you do the actual deletions need to loop back wards.  Use a Regular For Loop that loops backwards.  `For i = Ubound(delCols) to Lbound(delCols) Step -1`.

Comment: @ScottCraner

`For delme = UBound(delCols) To LBound(delCols) Step -1



            With finalsheet
                .Columns(delme).delete()
            End With



        Next
`

causes delCols to be highlightd as unrecognized. Do I need to put anything else in there to look at my list titled delCols?

Comment: Change `.Columns(delme).delete()` tp `.Columns(delCols(delme)).Delete`

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, seems I also needed to convert delCols to an array.

Comment: @ScottCraner It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the second delete loop. It worked!

```
        Dim colRay As Long() = delCols.ToArray


    For delme = UBound(colRay) To LBound(colRay) Step -1



        With finalsheet
            .Columns(delCols(delme)).Delete()
        End With



    Next
```